# FCM token registration is not returning token every time

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

We are calling FCM generate token service in the back ground after login from mobile device. But in Android, we are not getting token and in IOS we are not getting token for OS 12.0.*.

In QA/DEV/UAT environments, it is working fine.

We tried to look our issue on stack overflow but did not get any correct link.

It seems to me that token is not getting called for the first time when user download the app for the first time. If he will uninstall the app/ clear the data then token is getting registered.

We are using below code to generate the token for Android.

Comment: public void onNewToken(String token) {
 Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
 sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}

Comment: i didin't fully understand your issue but i retrieve my token using FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); i don't see it anywhere in your method.
And don't you have a class extending FirebaseInstanceIdService? in there you have a method onTokenRefresh() you can call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); to get your token in there

Comment: thanks for your comment. We will try below.

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String mToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
           Log.e("Token",mToken);
     }
 });